# Email plugin not available

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am working on `cordova` email composer to send emails. But I am getting the error `"email plugin not available"` when I tried to execute the app.

When I add

`< gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.2" />`

to the config file I am getting errors. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // specify contact search criteria
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts
        options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results
        filter = ["displayName"];   // return contact.displayName field

        // find contacts
        navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact){
        console.log("The following contact has been selected:" + JSON.stringify(contact));
    },function(err){
        console.log("Error: " + err);
    });
}

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onSuccess(contacts) {
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
            alert(contacts[i].displayName);
        }
    };

    // onError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onError(contactError) {
        alert("onError!");
    };
document.addEventListener("deviceready", draftEmail, false);
function draftEmail(subject, message) {
    if (!cordova.plugin){
        //non-mobile - plugins are not present.
        alert("Email plugin is not available");  
        return;
    }
    if (!isAvailable){
        //mobile, but no email installed
        alert("Email is not available")
        return;
    }
cordova.plugins.email.addAlias('gmail', 'com.google.android.gm');
    cordova.plugins.email.open({
        app: 'gmail',
    subject: 'Sent from Gmail',
        body: 'How are you?',
        isHtml: true
    })
}

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Config file:

```
<feature name="EmailComposer"> <param name="android-package" value="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.emailComposer.EmailComposer" /> </feature> 
<feature><gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.0" /></feature>
</widget>
```

Comment: are you building locally or on PhoneGapBuild service?

Comment: i'm building locally on my laptop using android emulator.

Comment: You need to use the CLI to install plugins. The line in `config.xml` is for PhoneGapBuild service only. You want to run `cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer` and then `cordova build` to add this locally.

Comment: followed your instructions but got the same error - Email plugin not available

Comment: did you remove the lines from the config file?

Comment: Yes, i removed the lines.

Comment: How are you deploying the app? Are you using the PhoneGap Developer app and using `phonegap serve`?

Comment: Yes I am using cordova developer and developing an android app...

Comment: The Cordova developer App only supports a certain number of plugins. This one is probably not supported. I will verify though. You will need to deploy directly to your device if this is the case.

Comment: Yes, i am deploying it on AVD android device...

Comment: ok. still working on my code. i'm not getting sleep as i want to achieve it...

Comment: So just got official word from PhoneGap, you cannot use thirdparty plugins when deploying via `phonegap serve` you need to use `phonegap run` and deploy directly to the device not the developer app.

Answer (score 0):

In draftEmail, you are checking for cordova.plugin but not cordova.plugins, hence you are getting the error alert.

Cross-answering your cross-post :)