# send e-mail in android using cordova

Tags: javascript, android, email, cordova

how to send e-mail in android using cordova. i've been trying since two days but i'm getting an error like e-mail plugin not available. been trying with this code but cannot get my desired result. dont know were the problem is...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    navigator.contacts.pickContact(onSuccess, function(contact){
        console.log('The following contact has been selected:' + JSON.stringify(contact));
    },function(err){
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", draftEmail, false);
function draftEmail(subject, message) {
    if (!cordova.plugin){
        //non-mobile - plugins are not present.
        alert("Email plugin is not available");  
        return;
    }
    if (!isAvailable){
        //mobile, but no email installed
        alert("Email is not available")
        return;
    }
cordova.plugins.email.addAlias('gmail', 'com.google.android.gm');
    cordova.plugins.email.open({
        app: 'gmail',
    to: 'abcd@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Sent from Gmail',
        body: 'How are you?',
        isHtml: true
    })
}

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are getting the error about plugin not being available, then you should be checking your config files and plugin registration. How did you add plugin to your app?

Comment: i added plugin through CLI using cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console... CONFIG : <feature name="Console"> <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" /> </feature>

Comment: Aha - any reply from this command? Success?

Comment: Yes. it was installed successfully but i am not getting the output.

Comment: User already has an open question for this exact topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610738/email-plugin-not-available?noredirect=1#comment43653121_27610738

Answer (score 0):

In draftEmail, you are checking for cordova.plugin but not cordova.plugins, hence you are getting the error alert.