# Cordova EmailComposer plugin

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use EmailComposer plugin with Cordova 5.0.0 and JQueryMobile.
I've installed the plugin ([here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)) using CLI. I'm testing using Phonegap App.

I have used the recommended syntax:

```
$("#btSend").on('touchstart', function(event) {                 
    console.log('--> @send');
    cordova.plugins.email.open({
        to:      'max@mustermann.de',
        subject: 'Greetings',
        body:    '<h1>Nice greetings from Leipzig</h1>'}
    );
    return false;
});
```

But the code is not working. Trying to debug, I've placed under the "onDeviceReady" event handler:

```
console.log('--> @1: '+ (window.cordova===undefined).toString() );
console.log('--> @2: '+  (cordova.plugins===undefined).toString() );
console.log('--> @3: '+ (cordova.plugins.email===undefined).toString() );
```

The outputs are:

```
--> @1: false
--> @2: true
nothings appears here
```

Could you help me to find why the email plugin is not working?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Well, after some additional search I've found that "Phonegap App" doesn't support external plugins. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610738/email-plugin-not-available). I've compiled the code and tested it directly on the device: the e-mail client opens and it's working as expected. Many thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Phonegap App" doesn't support external plugins. According with: (stackoverflow.com/questions/27610738/email-plugin-not-available)

Answer (score 0):

Check your other plugins.  If you're using other plugins, and one of them fouls up, it can tend to break your cordova.js, which in turn breaks cordova.plugins.  If you start with a brand new project, and simply add that specific plugin, it works. I tried. So, my bet would be that some other code is fouling up, and breaking cordova.js somehow. Try using a clean project, and running your code. Also, take a closer look at your javascript console, in case other code is inadvertenly breaking cordova.js.

Comment: I've created a new project, added the plugin with CLI and added to the "onDeviceReady" handler: cordova.plugins.email.open(); Nothing happen...